# Сценарий диалога с пользователем

Tags: javascript

Помогите разработать сценарий, который организует диалог с пользователем и позволяет сделать перевод некоторой суммы денег в гривнах в евро и доллары по определенному курсу.

Answer (score 4):

```
var euro_rate = 10.8;
var dollar_rate = 7.95;
val = prompt("Введите сумму в гривнах","");
alert("Сумма в евро: "+String(euro_rate*val));
alert("Сумма в долларах: "+String(dollar_rate*val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Друзья мои, если Вы немного познакомитесь с литературой на тему правильного проектирования взаимодействия с пользователем (очень рекомендую книжки Алана Купера), Вы придёте к выводу, что подобное взаимодействие ни в коем случае нельзя строить на диалоговых окнах.

Так что я не очень понимаю, какого рода помощь требуется. Нарисовать html-формочку?

---

Если же речь идёт не о реальном приложении, а об учебном задании, то это следовало указать в метках вопроса.

Comment: Это учебный скорее всего, только менять теги я не стал так как явно этого не указано в вопросе.

Конечно в коммерческих приложениях такого никто не делает)

Ну а если делать для себя, а не по ТЗ - то тут уже на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные)